# Creative/secure ways to protect data based on a shared secret in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I've been experimenting with some basic cryptography techniques in Java (my preferred programming language) and have a simple example that uses modular exponentiation to generate a shared secret between two client pairs.

But, given a shared secret, what are some simple-to-implement (yet secure) methods for actually *using* this secret to encrypt/decrypt or scramble/unscramble data being sent over the wire?

For example, if I have the String:

```
"So long, and thanks for all the fish"
```

And the shared secret (`BigInteger`):

```
1110278255331388386297296974141977
```

How can the String be sent over the wire in a way that allows for the clients to understand each other, while ensuring that without the shared secret, no middle man can interpret it?

**I'm not asking for a finished implementation**, just ideas or references to algorithms/techniques that can be used. I'm also avoiding relying on existing programs or APIs (like public/private keys) since this is just a side project for my own educational purposes.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you're just looking for secret key encryption algorithms like AES (or DES, or triple-DES, ...). Don't try to implement your own algorithm: it's a **very** complex task.

Comment: You want to roll your own? Good luck sir

Comment: "creative security" is an oxymoron.

Comment: Your native language? Did your parents raise you with Java?

Comment: I'm not looking for anything incredibly intense, just simple ideas that can be used. Eg. a way that would result in the secret key `1` resulting in a different scrambled String than `26`, or `52`, or `4000`, etc.

Comment: "Shared secret" means a simple private key encryption.  You can find several algorithms on the net.  For "educational" purposes you can "roll your own", but it will be nowhere near as secure as one of the standard ones.

Comment: One simple approach is to seed an RNG with your shared secret, then XOR successive random numbers with the "plaintext".  This scheme is very susceptible to "known plaintext" attacks, though.  More sophisticated/secure (and closer to "real" algorithms) would be to somehow "feedback" the output of the encryption into the RNG, so that the random sequence is modified by the data.

Comment: Shared secret key encryption is commonly called symmetric encryption.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, this is exactly the kind of idea I'm looking for!

Comment: @rob Thank you - that keyword ("symmetric encryption") is turning up lots of what I was hoping to find.

Comment: And you can further complicate the encryption by using a "salt" value -- a random number that is pre-pended to the plaintext (and thrown away on the other end).  This way, even if the same plaintext is sent through multiple times it will encrypt differently each time.

Comment: Please (re)read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  This type of question elicits a discussion (hence all the comments) and not a specific answer, and this is "not constructive" for SO.  This is probably appropriate for [programmers.se].

Comment: @JimGarrison Ah, I had no idea *Programmers* existed. I agree that this question definitely leans more toward discussion than a discrete, code-able answer. My fault. StackOverflow, SuperUser, now Programmers. Another SE subsite to bookmark. :)

Comment: While I applaud people spending their spare time educating themselves with such projects, I have to wonder if your time is better spent learning more about the existing cryptographic algorithms in use today. I fear the techniques you learn if you "roll your own" will be unlikely to assist you in implementing secure systems in the future with "standard" cryptography.

Comment: @craig Also note the existence of http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a standard way of doing what you are after and that is called password-based key derivation. You need to use a secure symmetric encryption algorithm. You can of course go for asymmetric ones like RSA, but with a shared secret, that is redundant.

However, you don't want to use your shared secret directly.

1. Your shared secret may have an inappropriate size to be used as a key. For example, AES, as a good choice, accepts 128-bit and 256-bit keys and the shared secret may not be a good match.
2. The key for your symmetric algorithm of choice should be secure enough, which means that it should have a secure level of randomness which your shared secret may lack.

This is exactly the case algorithms like PBKDF2 (password-based key derivation function 2) are invented for. PBKDF2 is already implemented in standard java and you may use it. It generates a secure key with arbitrary size based on a "passphrase", which is simply the shared secret in this case. These family of algorithms have a iteration parameter, which indicates how many times a hash function is applied to derive the key. Make sure to set it to a high number like a few thousand.

I should note though that security (confidentiality and integrity of transmitted data) in this cases relies on your shared secret to be actually secret. I don't know how you are generating it, but you need to make sure that the process is secure. [Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) is a good example. If you are not familiar with this, I recommend you to take a look and see what is does to ensure that the process is safe.

As it is already stated in the comments, you don't need to (and also should not) innovate in cryptography for a practical application. You will find anything you need already implemented and proven secure. Take my last sentence with a grain of salt though.